# How to define the `window` object in QScriptEngine

Tags: javascript, c++, qt

### The JavaScript `window` object

In JavaScript, browsers have a global object `window`. This object has some interesting propreties:

```
var any = 5;
console.log(window.any);
```

The `window` object act as a namespace, where all variables are created inside.

This behavior is not (by default) active while using `QScriptEngine` of Qt, which is a general purpose JS engine and does not have those browsers specific capabilities.

The question is:

**How to get `QScriptEngine` to have this `window` object?** (With similar behavior)

---

#### Tries

Supposing a simple C++ project including `Qt` (currently 5.7), the following code parse some JS and shows the results:

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QScriptEngine>
#include <QCoreApplication>

//Logger class, for console.log
class Logger: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Logger( QObject*parent = nullptr): QObject(parent) {}

public slots:
    void log(const QString& str){ qDebug() << str; }
};

#include "test.moc"

int main(int argn, char* args[])
{
    QCoreApplication app(argn, args);
    QScriptEngine engine;
    // Logger
    Logger logger;
    QScriptValue loggerResult = engine.newQObject(&logger);
    engine.globalObject().setProperty("console", loggerResult);

    // TODO CONFIG HERE FOR WINDOW OBJECT
    //engine.globalObject().setProperty(QString("window"), 
    //    engine.newObject()); //Does not work, obviously

    engine.evaluate("var test=42; console.log(test); console.log(window.test)");
    if (engine.hasUncaughtException()) 
    {
        int line = engine.uncaughtExceptionLineNumber();
        QScriptValue error = engine.uncaughtException();
        QStringList errorStr = engine.uncaughtExceptionBacktrace();
        qDebug() << "Exception at:" << line << ":" << error.toString();
    }
}
```

Output:

> "42"
>   ""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign `this` to a `window` variable:

```
engine.evaluate("window=this; var test=42; console.log(test); console.log(window.test)");
```

Output:

> "42"
>   "42"

There is a blog post in Qt Blog about [Faking a web browser environment in QtScript](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2011/03/04/faking-a-web-browser-environment-in-qtscript/).